# OMNET++: INET 4.0 How to obtain beacon frame signal power in the app layer?

Tags: omnet++, rssi, inet, application-layer

I'm using `INET` 4.0 framework for OMNET++ and I'm trying to obtain the received signal power of the beacon frames sent by Access Points at my AdhocHost's app layer.
I am well aware that it is possible to use to the `SignalPowerInd` tag for that purpose, however, how may I modify my mac layer to allow beacon frames (or at least their RSS value) to be delivered to my app?